# Using custom dimension / custom metric to set trial start date

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to associate a user with a starting date. Ie the date a user starts to use a service.

When using a custom dimension you can set values with the scope: user so that the starting date will be associated with that user. However, custom dimensions are only text fields. So even if set the date there as a text field you won't be able to group a range of dates in a nice way.

When using the custom metric there is a formatting type called time. But the scope is only Hit or Product. So it seems that the datapoint will only be associated with that point in time rather than with the user overall.

So my question is what would the most beneficial way of storing a starting date in Google Analytics be which allows you to slice and dice data the best way in their UI.

Comment: Could you set the date in such a way that would be easy to group, say, via regex?

Comment: Have you looked at using the dateOfSession segment condition to accomplish what you are trying to do? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dateOfSession-conditions